# Symfony2 and DateTimePicker bad date format?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, symfony, datepicker

I am trying to select a datetime with a symfony form.
This is my form :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('formation_date','datetime',array('label' => "Séance le :",
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'date', 'readonly' => 'readonly')
        ))               
    ;
}
```

And I am using a jquery datetimepicker.
This is my script on the page to adjust the data :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.datepicker.setDefaults(
    $.extend(
        {'dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'},
        $.datepicker.regional['fr']
    )
);
$.timepicker.setDefaults(
    $.extend(
        {'timeFormat':'hh:mm:00'}
    )
);
  jQuery('.date').datetimepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim.','Lun.','Mar.','Mer.','Jeu.','Ven.','Sam.'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    closeText: 'Fermer',
    prevText: 'Précédent',
    nextText: 'Suivant',
    minDate: "y", 
    maxDate: "+10y"
    });
});
</script>
```

But the time is not correct in the database. Although I post string '21/06/2014 12:00:00' (length=19 it is 00:00:00 in database and in my entity after handleRequest.

```
    > object(DateTime)[809]
public 'date' => string '2014-06-21 00:00:00' (length=19)
public 'timezone_type' => int 1
public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

And I have
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (21/06/2014 12:00:00) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character 
if I try to do this :

```
$date = new DateTime($request->request->get('intranet_rhbundle_dateformation')["formation_date"]);
```

so, I have no idea to solve it...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'format' => 'd/m/Y H:i',` ?

Comment: On the form ? No, if I put this, I have : "The "format" option should contain the letters "y", "M" and "d". Its current value is "d/m/Y H:i". " ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Failed to parse time string` problem, try this :

```
$date = new DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    $request->request->get('intranet_rhbundle_dateformation')["formation_date"]
);
```

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: The formation_date is a DateTime field in my entity :
 /**
  *
  * @var string $formation_date
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="formation_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
  * @Assert\DateTime()
  **/
 private $formation_date;
And the "new" is not needed.
With your proposition, I have :
object(DateTime)[779]
  public 'date' => string '2014-06-19 12:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
Wich is good :) I try with this date and hope it will works.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($request->request->get('intranet_rhbundle_dateformation')["formation_date"])` ?

Comment: I try with your bad date format before you edit it and I saw the obvious error after post my comment. Sorry !

Comment: Yes, the final method is not very clean but it is working !
I hope anybody will found the correct configuration to don't need to use a datetime variable.
Your answer is correct thank's you ! :)